# Installing packages that require system restart, from a Juju charm

Tags: upstart, juju

I'm writing a Juju charm that installs some new packages, some of which require a system restart.

In particular, daemontools-run installs an Upstart file, which would start svcanboot on the next system restart.  There's no "service" file, so "service svscanboot start" wouldn't work.

Is there a way my charm can either: request a system restart; or, start the service itself?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to start an Upstart service is  `start service-name`  like:

```
start svscan
```

The Juju charm can execute this command in the install hook (or any other appropriate hook).